# How to display ListView items as 1 item in 1 row?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a ListView where If item length is small multiple items are getting displayed in same line. I would like to have them 1 item in 1 row. Please refer below image for better understanding.

[image: ListView]

I have tried the `View` options like `LargeIcon`, `SmallIcon`, `List` but none are according to my requirement.

I have also tried details view but the items are not visible though getting inserted. Please find below images for reference.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwm1Y.png)

Comment: You probably missed the `Details` view (requires a Column. If you don't like the Header, set  `HeaderStyle = none`).

Comment: I tried your suggestion what is happening with details view is that the items are not visible when added. For other views items are visible.

Comment: This time, you missed the *requires a Column* part.

Comment: @Jimi I am new to windows forms. Can you please help me with an example?

Comment: Click your ListView, in the Properties panel look for the `Columns` property, click the `[...]` button, add a Column, set its Width (eventually), confirm, done. Don't like to see the Columns header? Set `HeaderStyle = none` (`HeaderStyle` is also a Property you can find in the Properties panel).

Comment: The problem is if the items are more then the listview window size it is adding the items horizontally which otherwise should be vertically. Anyway to achieve such behavior?

Comment: The problem is that you didn't follow the steps I suggested. In Details view, the list Items are presented vertically.

Comment: I have tried details view and yes items are inserted vertically but they are not not visible (edited the description for your reference). Could you please help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: You didn't add a Column.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi for all your help. Because of some lines of code it was not adding in listview. Now its working.

Comment: You're welcome :)